# 'Error inflating class Button' despite working before

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-support-library, android-button

After implementing some buttons within my layout the following error appears within the logcat during app deployment:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class Button

I really don't understand why this is happening when it was working fine before.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Information_textView"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/information"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/Information_tableLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/Information_textView">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Information_btnMale"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_male"
                    android:text="@string/male"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="30sp"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Information_btnFemale"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/female"
                    android:text="@string/female"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="30sp"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Java**

```
public class FragmentInformation extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    public FragmentInformation() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.information, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = getView();
        assert v != null;


        button0 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.Information_btnMale);
        button0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                HeaderDialog headerDialog = new HeaderDialog(getActivity());
                headerDialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.male);                headerDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.male_information);
                headerDialog.setNegativeButton("OK", null);
            }
        });


        Button button1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.Information_btnFemale);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                HeaderDialog headerDialog = new HeaderDialog(getActivity());
                headerDialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.female);
                headerDialog.setNegativeButton("OK", null);
            }
        });


        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
06-27 18:44:58.214 7756-7756/com.companyname.informationapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: com.companyname.informationapp, PID: 7756
                                                                                    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #413: Error inflating class Button
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                                        at com.companyname.informationapp.FragmentInformation.onCreateView(FragmentInformation.java:30)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1984)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:626)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:166)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:668)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:630)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:611)
```

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, you may have upgraded from Support Library 23.2.0,after which changes were made

Due to memory usage and Configuration updating issues  it was  removed in 23.3.0. In 23.4.0, same functionality was added but it needs to be enabled manually

```
static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromSourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Where does this need to go? The Support Library used in my project is 25.3.1, which I upgraded to recently

Comment: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}